# Paste from Range Object to Word document

Tags: vba, object, ms-word, range, paste

How do I paste without pulling from the clipboard?

(The code examples are excerpts from Googling and recording.)

My VBA code populates a section of my document from a form. Before loading the next form, it copies that section's contents to an object.

The code goes on to further populate the document. When done, the user can choose the "Next Page" control which generates a new page.
I want to paste the object I saved to the beginning of that new page.

My code up to the point of the paste.

```vb
Sub waiverCopy()
    Dim objRange As Range
    'Capture first section of document (waiver with names etc. populated)
    Set objRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.End)
    
    Debug.Print objRange               'DOES PRINT contents in immediate window
    
    ' continue populating rest of current page '
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory     'position to end of document (i.e. current page)
    
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak  'start new page
    
    ' Nothing of the myriad of things I've tried will paste the contents of objRange on new page

End Sub
```

Comment: You **paste** from the clipboard. Clipboards allow different programs to exchange data. Before the clipboard was invented Word had copy text and move text commands to.  Shift+F2 and F2.

Comment: @KL-1 there is no need to use the clipboard within the VBA scope, you can use the objects instead. Please see proposed answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t want to use the clipboard, all you are missing is to insert the range object on the current `Selection` position (`Selection.FormattedText = objRange`) just after creating the Page Break.

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim objRange As Range
    'Capture first section of document (waiver with names etc. populated)
    Set objRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.End - 1)
      
    ' continue populating rest of current page '
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory     'position to end of document (i.e. current page)
    
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak  'start new page
            
    Selection.FormattedText = objRange
    
    ' Don´t forget to clean memory
    Set objRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please do not forget to clean memory with `Set objRange = Nothing`.

Comment: There is no need to *clean memory*. `End Sub` will reclaim all memory.

Comment: You are partially right, the garbage collector will take care of it after the object goes out of scope (after End Sub), but you don´t know when, so the object may exists longer than absolutely necessary. You can test it yourself monitoring the memory resources handling a large enough object, try both scenarios and see the difference setting object to Nothing.

Comment: Thank you. So I gather that if my client went to get a cup of coffee or whatnot before continuing,  or the session takes a long time, what I have captured in objRange may get garbage collected before the client return / finishes.?

Comment: No. There is Excel and it's data. And there is VBA and it's data. Your range is temporary - it only exists from when you create it to when you destroy it, and that happens when you implicitly or explicitly tell VBA to reclaim the memory (which is 16 bytes). We are talking about a reference to your data not the data itself.